# Reading .txt file and printing results

Tags: c, arrays, file, io

I'm trying to read the information I printed to a .txt file from a separate program, and display it in this new program. Although when I run the program, it says the file cannot be found. I suspect its my code, and not the file location as I have double checked my hard code, here is what I have so far, if anyone could point me in the right direction that would be great!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define ARRAY_SIZE      21

typedef struct data_slice
{
    int t;      // -> Time
    float tp;   // -> Valve pressure
    float tf;   // -> Sodium flow
    float tt;   // -> Sodium temp in Celsius
} data_slice;

void printIt(data_slice * data);

int main()
{
   float num;
   FILE *fptr;
   data_slice data[ARRAY_SIZE];

   if ((fptr =     fopen("/Users/captainrogers/Documents/output_data.txt","r")) == NULL){
       printf("Error! opening file");

       // Program exits if the file pointer returns NULL.
       exit(1);
   }

   fscanf(fptr,"%f \n", &num);

    printIt(data);

   fclose(fptr);

   return 0;
}
void printIt(data_slice * data)
{
    // Find the indice holding the time value of -10
    int indice = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; ++i)
    {
        if (data[i].t == -10)
        {
            indice = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    // Print results to screen
    for (int i = 0, temp = indice; i < ARRAY_SIZE; ++i)
    {
        printf("%i\t %f\t %f\t %f\n", data[temp].t, data[temp].tp,     data[temp].tf, data[temp].tt);
        temp = (temp + 1) % ARRAY_SIZE;
    }

}
```

Data I'm trying to print from .txt:

```
-10  595.000000  15.000000   167.000000
 -9  557.000000  17.000000   168.000000
 -8  634.000000  17.000000   114.000000
 -7  656.000000  10.000000   183.000000
 -6  561.000000  13.000000   139.000000
 -5  634.000000  17.000000   124.000000
 -4  672.000000  19.000000   155.000000
 -3  527.000000  14.000000   166.000000
 -2  656.000000  11.000000   188.000000
 -1  661.000000  18.000000   141.000000
  0  689.000000  17.000000   146.000000
  1  624.000000  11.000000   104.000000
  2  504.000000  20.000000   120.000000
  3  673.000000  18.000000   147.000000
  4  511.000000  12.000000   114.000000
  5  606.000000  14.000000   171.000000
  6  601.000000  13.000000   159.000000
  7  602.000000  11.000000   127.000000
  8  684.000000  10.000000   194.000000
  9  632.000000  16.000000   139.000000
 10  651.000000  13.000000   168.000000
```

Comment: It looks like you're on a macOS system. Remember that on POSIX systems (like macOS and Linux) file and directory names are *case-sensitive*. I also recommend you print out the value of `errno` directly after `fopen` return a null pointer, perhaps in printable form using e.g. `perror`.

Comment: Well, I just created a random file and tried your code and it worked without any modifications (except the file path).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude:  the default filesystem type (HFS+) on OS X (mac) is case-insensitive by default.  You *can* create case sensitive filesystems on mac (Case-Sensitive HFS+), but most don't.

Comment: @BarisYakut What did the output look like? Did it look like the way I have the output text formatted above?

Comment: @BlakeRogers No, it was mostly zeros. Tested on macOS Sierra and compiled with gcc.

Comment: '_mostly zeros_' because nothing is read into `data[]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
fopen("/Users/captainrogers/Documents/output_data.txt","r")
```

If the file can't be found, double-check your path. Maybe first try with the full path including the drive letter.

```
fscanf(fptr,"%f \n", &num);
```

Always check the return-value of `fscanf()`. `"%f \n"` is probably not the format string you want.

```
printIt(data);
```

**Main problem**: you never read any data into `data[]`.

Answer (score 0):

fptr =     fopen("C://Users//captainrogers//Documents//output_data.txt","r"))
try this code if you are sure your document is in the right file.